# Python: For loop Concatenation

Tags: python

```
cat = "["
for row in res:
    cat = cat  + (str((row['weeks'])) + ',')

cat = (cat + "]").replace(',]', ']')
```

The above bit of code gives a result string as:

```
[30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
```

However what I want is:

```
[W30,W31,W32,W33,W34,W35,W36,W37,W38,W39,W40]
```

I have been unsuccessful in concatenating the `W` before each number. How could I do this?
This is the unsuccessful code that I tried:

```
cat = cat  + (str('W'+ (row['weeks'])) + ',')
```

Comment: Are you trying to make an actual list when this is done, or do you actually want a string?

Comment: I want the result to be a string but in the above mentioned format.

Comment: What's wrong with `'W{},'.format(row[weeks])`?

Comment: @dhke: It gives `W[30, 31, ..., 40],`.

Comment: Ah! Please add an example of the contents of `row['weeks']`. This will probably stop other guesses.

Comment: @dhke  The contents are `30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40`. Mentioned in the question.

Comment: @TauseefHussain That's the result string, `row['weeks']` seems to be a list of numbers. I got confused about the contents. Doesn't matter now, there's an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done this

```
cat = cat  + (str('W'+ (row['weeks'])) + ',')
```

It should be

```
cat = cat  + ('W'+ str(row['weeks']) + ',')
```

if you want it to be a list you could do this

```
cat = ["W"+str(row['weeks']) for row in res]
```

Comment: Your initial answer was great, thank you so much. I later realised that I need the final answer in the form of a JSON Object hence the final edit was: `cat = cat  + ('"W'+ str((row['weeks'])) + '",')` `cat = (cat + "]").replace(',]', ']')`

Comment: you are welcome but do see others way it might be efficient and help full for you :)

Comment: So my final list was `["W30","W31","W32","W33","W34","W35","W36","W37","W38","W39","W40"]`

Answer (score 2):

This gives the desired string:

```
cat = '[{}]'.format(','.join('W{}'.format(i) for i in row['weeks']))
#                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                            this gives 'W30', 'W31', etc.
#                   ^^^^^^^^^
#                   this joins them with commas: 'W30,W31,...,W40'
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#     this puts [ ] around
```

Answer (score 1):

**code:**

```
cat = '[W' + ',W'.join(str(element) for element in row['weeks']) + ']'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting an answer from here (since there are many ways to do it), you should understand what went wrong with your own code.

```
(str('W'+ (row['weeks'])) + ',')
```

What is the order of operations here?

1. We find `row['weeks']`.
2. We attempt `'W'` + that.
3. We attempt `str` on that.
4. We attempt that + `','`.

Presumably, `row['weeks']` is an integer, so the addition with `'W'` will fail. You must do this **after** applying `str` to the integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list made of strings do

```
cat = [ 'W'+str(row['weeks']) for row in res]
```

and, if you want a single string, turn the list into a string

```
string_cat = str(cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat = "[" + ",".join('W' + str(row['weeks']) for row in res) + "]"
```

For each `row` in `res` convert `row['weeks']` to string, prefix it with 'W', and join all such strings with the `','` character. Then just add opening `[` and closing `]`.